# Tab like structure in CSS with rounded corners

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS rectangle that has rounded corners. I would like to add a tab like structure on top of it.

This is what I am talking about.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOP6w.png

I tried making two different elements and adding together with positioning but it doesnot look real(mainly because of shadow)l. Can we make it on CSS on a single element?

Thanks in advance!

Edit(more details):

I have a rectangle with rounded border as follows:

```
#mybox
{
width: 800px;
height:400px;
border:thin;
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;   
border-color:black;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 5px #000;  
}
```

I want to tweak/stretch the top part to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOP6w.png).

Comment: Can you at least show us what you have tried?  It may only need a minor tweak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the :before selector to create what you're asking for.

Here's a quick implementation to give you an idea on how to use it:

```
<div class="foo"></div>

.foo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 4px solid #000;
    margin-top: 24px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.foo:before {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 4px solid #000;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -24px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank You Drawrdesign, appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code...

```
<div style="width: 93px; height: 72px;">
  <div style="width: 93px; height: 13px; background-image: url('tabtop.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-position: left top"></div>
  <div style="width: 93px; height: 59px; background-image: url('tabbottom.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-position: left top"></div>
</div>
```

With the images below...
If you size the divs to the image you should be fine and use them as a BACKGROUND property means you can have text in the actual divs

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just copy and paste the code into a NEW html file to test it, also when you customise your actual pages make sure to size the DIVS to the SAME size as your images.

Comment: Actually, the problem is with the shadow. If I use images then I will have to add shadow before-hand. Just trying to use as less images as possible. Thanks anyway

Comment: Oh you have added CSS since your last edit, so my solution isn't right now, but i will look at it again later.

Answer (score 1):

why not use something prepackaged like bootstrap or jquery ui which have tab functionality?  i can understand if you want to build your own thing but maybe you want a shortcut?

bootstrap:  http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

jquery ui:   http://jqueryui.com/

there are numerous such packages available to help your ui development but these are two common ones

Comment: Awesome, jquery-ui looks like the better options. Thanks!